# How to create a Python object that holds an empty list

Tags: python, list, object, instantiation

I am a Java programmer struggling to learn Python, and almost certainly about to ask a duplicate question.  In my Python code, I need to create an object that basically holds a list.  When an object is instantiated, the list is to be empty.  Later in the code, I want to add items:

```
   1     #!/usr/bin/python
   2
   3     class objWithList:
   4       # myList                 # define a global variable here?
   5       def __init__(self):
   6         print "New Object created!"
   7         myList = list()        # tell Python "myList" is a list?
   8       def addSomething(cls, x):
   9         myList.append(x)
  10     
  11     myObj = objWithList()      # create the object
  12     str1 = "Add me"
  13     myObj.addSomething(str1)   # add item to obj's list
```

When I run the above code, I get this error message:

```
   me@myBox/python_Sandbox# ./test1.py
   New Object created!
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./test1.py", line 13, in <module>
       myObj.addSomething(str1)   # add item to obj's list
     File "./test1.py", line 9, in addSomething
       myList.append(x)
   NameError: global name 'myList' is not defined
   me@myBox/python_Sandbox#
```

So it looks like the object is successfully created, but when I call `addSomething()`, the list is not defined.  Is that because the myList created in `__init__()` goes out of scope once the object constructor is completed?  I get the same error message when I move the `myList = list()` command to the top of the class definition:

```
   3     class objWithList:
   4       myList = list()              # moved list creation here
   5       def __init__(self):
   6         print "New Object created!"
   7       def addSomething(cls, x):
   8         myList.append(x)
```

So how do I create an empty list which is available after the object is created?

I should also add that I am writing on Python 2.7.  My company likes this version, so I'm stuck with it.  Don't ask.

Thanks

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading an introductory tutorial on classes in Python, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html, because you have several basic errors here.

Comment: For now, think of `self` as `this` when you are coming from Java. `myList = list()` does not do much good if you don't bind it to the instance you are creating. (i.e. use `self.myList = list()`). Also, `[]` is a shorthand for `list()`.

Comment: This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: You've created two local variables named `myList`; since the second tries to reference an existing value, the compiler assumes that it's *supposed* to be a global you neglected to define.  Research how to handle variable scoping in Python, especially class and instance attributes.

Comment: "...almost certainly about to ask a duplicate question" Then you probably should have researched it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__` function `myList` is just local variable. Use `self.myList` in order to make it as a class member. Of course access it in function addSomething() by using self as well: `self.myList.append(x)`. Also you need to change signature of method addSomething from `addSomething(cls, x)` to `addSomething(self, x)`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there is difference between `__init__` and `__new__`. That is, by the time your code hits `__init__` it is already "constructed". Only then you can add new "fields" to an instance, like for example `self.myList = []` in `__init__`.

What `def addSomething(cls, x)` goes, you may named it `cls` but it is the instance in fact. So you should write `self.myList.append()` instead.